# Фильтр выдающий результаты из массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, filter

Хочу сделать что-то вроде фильтра, однако не с сортировкой блоков, а именно вставкой данных из массива. То есть, изначально блок `.result` пустой. Скрипт видит активную ссылку и размещает данные сравнивая `CatID` из массива и `data-cat` из ссылки. При клике на ссылку, данные плавно исчезают и запрашиваются новые. Накидал минимальный код:

```js
var result=[
//['CatID','Name','Price','URL']
['1','Данные 1','123','http://sitetest.com/page1.html'],
['2','Данные 2','533','http://sitetest.com/page2.html']
['1','Данные 3','123','http://sitetest.com/page3.html'],
['1','Данные 4','533','http://sitetest.com/page4.html']
['1','Данные 5','123','http://sitetest.com/page5.html'],
['2','Данные 6','533','http://sitetest.com/page6.html']
];
```

```html
<div class="filter">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-cat="1">Вариант 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" data-cat="2">Вариант 2</a>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

На выходе код элементов внутри `.result` может быть любым. Например:

```
<a href="http://sitetest.com/page1.html">Данные 1 за $123</a>
```

Целиком писать все не обязательно, только чтоб понять сам принцип. Или хотя бы киньте ссылки на нужные функции для реализации. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто:
Ищем `.active` и выполняем функцию сортировки.
Клик по другой категории делает так же, только с другим ID.

Сама сортировка проще - фильтруем по ID, преобразуем данные в нужный шаблон и выводим его.

Я чуть упоролся, но, думаю, понятно:

```js
var result = [
  //['CatID','Name','Price','URL']
  ['1', 'Данные 1', '123', 'http://sitetest.com/page1.html'],
  ['2', 'Данные 2', '533', 'http://sitetest.com/page2.html'],
  ['1', 'Данные 3', '123', 'http://sitetest.com/page3.html'],
  ['1', 'Данные 4', '533', 'http://sitetest.com/page4.html'],
  ['1', 'Данные 5', '123', 'http://sitetest.com/page5.html'],
  ['2', 'Данные 6', '533', 'http://sitetest.com/page6.html']
];

document.querySelector('.filter').addEventListener('click', e => e.target.nodeName === 'A' ? (el = e.target, cat = el.dataset.cat, document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = result.filter(i => cat === i[0]).map(e => `<a href="{3}">{1} за \${2}</a>`.replace(/{(\d)}/g, (_, id) => id in e ? e[id] : `{${id}}`)).join('<br />')) : null);

document.querySelector('.active').click();
```

```html
<div class="filter">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-cat="1">Вариант 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" data-cat="2">Вариант 2</a>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

---

**UPD:**
Писать как выше - грех, за который надо бы хворостиной отходить создавшего.
Я просто не удержался :)

Вот пример на `jQuery` (просто замена стандартных функций на библиотечные; жуть, но раз народ просит...) с пояснениями:

```js
var result = [
  //['CatID','Name','Price','URL']
  ['1', 'Данные 1', '123', 'http://sitetest.com/page1.html'],
  ['2', 'Данные 2', '533', 'http://sitetest.com/page2.html'],
  ['1', 'Данные 3', '123', 'http://sitetest.com/page3.html'],
  ['1', 'Данные 4', '533', 'http://sitetest.com/page4.html'],
  ['1', 'Данные 5', '123', 'http://sitetest.com/page5.html'],
  ['2', 'Данные 6', '533', 'http://sitetest.com/page6.html']
];

$('.filter').on('click', 'a', function () {
  let cat = $(this).data('cat'); // Выбираем искомую категорию (int)
  let html = result
               .filter(i => cat === i[0]) // Оставляем только те массивы, у которых первый элемент равен искомой категории
               .map(e => `<a href="{3}">{1} за \${2}</a>`.replace(/{(\d)}/g, (_, id) => id in e ? e[id] : `{${id}}`))  // Преобразуем каждый объект в строку, где заменим каждый willcard в шаблоне на реальное значение ({0} - первый элемент, {1} - второй элемент и т. д.)
               .join('<br />'); // Склеиваем в строку через тэг переноса
  
  
  $('.result').html(html); // Заменяем прошлый .result новыми данными

$('.active').click(); // После того, как навесили обработчик, эмулируем клик по активной ссылке, чтобы сразу загрузить активную категорию
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-cat="1">Вариант 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" data-cat="2">Вариант 2</a>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Придется и мне упороться) Так не не все из написанного легко объяснимо из-за того, что я больше копаюсь с jQuery и намного меньше с условно новыми стандартами JS. К слову, насколько бы было проще такую же функцию сделать с её помощью? Если бы нашли пару минут на второй вариант - было бы супер, думаю, не только мне интересно. Ответ вполне достаточный, поэтому принимаю его. Спасибо большое за участие!

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev, на самом делен изменений я бы не в нёс особых. Только `$(...).on` вместо `addEventListener`, `$(..).html` вместо `innerHTML` и подобное. Логика та же.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev, обновил.

Comment: Спасибо. И правда нет особых изменений) А Что скажете насчет jshint? почему он рекомендует не использовать "=>" или "let"?

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev, Зависит от настроек `esversion`. Ставьте 6 и не будет ошибок.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант на jQuery со сменой .active

```js
var result=[
//['CatID','Name','Price','URL']
['1','Данные 1','123','http://sitetest.com/page1.html'],
['2','Данные 2','533','http://sitetest.com/page2.html'],
['1','Данные 3','123','http://sitetest.com/page3.html'],
['1','Данные 4','533','http://sitetest.com/page4.html'],
['1','Данные 5','123','http://sitetest.com/page5.html'],
['2','Данные 6','533','http://sitetest.com/page6.html']
],
output=$('.result');

$('.filter').on('click','a',function() {
  btn=$(this);
  $('.filter a').removeClass('active');
  btn.addClass('active');
  output.empty();
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i][0]===btn.attr('data-cat')) {
        output.append('<div><a href="'+result[i][3]+'">'+result[i][1]+' за $'+result[i][2]+'</a></div>');
      }
  }
})

$('.active').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-cat="1">Вариант 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-cat="2">Вариант 2</a>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Первый вариант без jQuery и без класса active

```js
var result=[
//['CatID','Name','Price','URL']
['1','Данные 1','123','http://sitetest.com/page1.html'],
['2','Данные 2','533','http://sitetest.com/page2.html'],
['1','Данные 3','123','http://sitetest.com/page3.html'],
['1','Данные 4','533','http://sitetest.com/page4.html'],
['1','Данные 5','123','http://sitetest.com/page5.html'],
['2','Данные 6','533','http://sitetest.com/page6.html']
];

var filters = document.getElementsByClassName("filters");
var output = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

function filterIt() {
    var catId = this.getAttribute("data-cat");
    output[0].innerHTML='';
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i][0]===catId) {
          var d = document.createElement("div");
          d.innerHTML='<a href="'+result[i][3]+'">'+result[i][1]+' за $'+result[i][2]+'</a>';
          output[0].appendChild(d);
        }
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    filters[i].addEventListener('click', filterIt, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filters active" data-cat="1">Вариант 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="filters" data-cat="2">Вариант 2</a>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант мне намного более понятен, но, немного не полный. То есть, сразу не выдает данных по активной ссылке. Это не критично лично для меня, я допишу недостающий участок, а для сервиса - ответ не полный. Поэтому приму второй, но, все равно, еще раз, спасибо!

Comment: я руководствовался "Целиком писать все не обязательно, только чтоб понять сам принцип" :)

Comment: Как уже написал, лично мне вполне достаточно вашего варианта, просто сам сервис направлен именно на сбор вопросов и решений, то есть, принятый более точный ответ будет более правильным для остальных, кому он так же будет полезен. Я бы выбрал оба, если бы мог)

Comment: добавил пример на jQuery с классом active

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за внимание. Я не стал уже менять принятый ответ. Прошелся по другим вашим ответам принятым и отметил интересные.